# T-SQL Подскажите как лучше построить модель?

Tags: база-данных, sql-server, linq

Форумчане, добрый день!
Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
Имеется следующая основная таблица (маловажные колонки опустил)

**MainTable**

```
{ 

  id_main (PK,Identity)

  id_operation (FK)

}
```

Для каждой операции существует разное количество атрибутов.
Например:

1. Покупка машины => Номер договора, стоимость автомобиля и т.д.
2. Переоформление авто => ФИО владельца, Номер авто и т.д.

Суть в том, что параметры почти для каждой операции разные. (Некоторые операции имеют одинаковые пар-ры)

При проектировании столкнулся с дилеммой как лучше сделать:

1. Создать одну дополнительную таблицу в который хранить все атрибуты
2. Создать несколько таблиц под каждую операцию.
3. Просто все атрибуты забить в главную таблицу.

Запрос будет генерировать Linq, поэтому в первом и третьем случае будут выгружаться абсолютно все колонки (Их будет ~25 и почти все nvarchar), а во втором будет будет много Join'ов по пустым полям.

Как лучше сделать с точки зрения высокой производительности и гибкости (добавятся новые операции или атрибуты)?

Comment: может быть посмотреть в сторону xml или json столбцов, т.е. будет одна таблица с основными столбцами и дополнительный столбец в котором будет xml/json определенной схемы.

Comment: Что такое в вашем понимании linq? Существуют такие библиотеки как linq2sql и entity framework, обе используют синтаксис linq для построения запросов к БД.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое решение зависит от того, как вы будете использовать данные: какие требования к отображению, фильтрации, отчётам и т.п. Моя рекомендация не учитывает требований к системе, поэтому будет из общей практики.

Я бы рекомендовал вариант два, но немного видоизменённый.

Создаётся одна общая таблица "Операции", в которой будут общие поля для всех операций. Например: тип операции, дата создания, объект (авто), название, описание и т.п. И уже оттуда делать ссылки на таблицы под каждую операцию.

Из плюсов:

- Упрощение задачи отображения данных. Очень часто пользователю, просматривая историю, достаточно видеть общие данные об операции (дата, тип, и т.п.), а потом уже открыть конкретную и смотреть детали. Т.е. при отображении искать надо будет только в одной таблице
- Упрощение задачи фильтрации по общим полям. Например не надо будет проверять поле "дата создания" в каждой таблице, а только в общей.
- Более оптимально будут работать индексы. Но на сколько - зависит от конкретных требований к фильтрации/поиску
- Другие плюсы варианта 2

Из минусов:

- Сам код будет чуть сложнее. Нужны транзакции при вводе/изменении/удалении, "умное" обновление полей (если меняем название - одна таблица, если спец. поле - другая таблица).
- Если по ТЗ операция может менять свой тип, то этот вариант не очень удобный, т.к. надо копировать и удалять записи, переписывать ссылки и т.п.

З.Ы. можно детальнее углубиться, но нужно знать более подробнее ТЗ и нюансы использования базы со стороны софта.

Comment: Если детали операции не участвуют в поиске, я бы предложил  еще упростить: общая таблица операций + остальные данные в той же таблице. Создаем поле Details типа nvarchar. Туда кладем специфичные данные операций в сериализованом в JSON виде. Тогда они могут иметь любую структуру, т.к. операции сериализации\десериализации будут происходить только на клиенте (в .NET)

Основной минус - такие поля только для хранения данный. Поиск и индексацию по ним осуществлять проблематично.